# Create jquery item from string without actually inserting into DOM?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to create a jquery object that I can perform jquery functions on from just a string representation?

I.e.

```
var item = '<div>hello</div>';
???
alert(item.html());
```

I think I could do it by adding it to the DOM using `append()`, then reselecting it, but i dont really want to do that as it seems horribly ineffcient.

EDIT: Thanks for all the replies

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var item = '<div>hello</div>';
alert($(item).html());
```

However the html() function displays the inner html of the object created.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a great solution, you can do the following:

```
var item = "<div>hjello</div>";
var itemSelector = $(item);
alert(itemSelector.html());
```

^_^

edit:

```
var item = "<div>hjello</div>";
alert($(item).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var item = $('<div>');
item.text('hello');

alert(item.text);
```

item is not a part of the DOM, you can manipuate it the way you like and append it where you like when you feel like it.

Answer (score -1):

```
var item = $.create('<div>hello</div>');
```

try that?